# Problem with deb installation

Tags: deb, alien

I converted minetest-classic-1402.00-src.tar.bz2 to minetest-classic_1402.00-1_all.deb using the software alien in the terminal, using the command,
`sudo alien -k minetest-classic-1402.00-src.tar.bz2`

After installing the .deb using GDebi installer, it says that it is installed.
I then go to the unity bar, and go to applications, and it is 'supposed' to be there, since I thought it was a software.

Comment: Which package are you trying to install?

Comment: How do you search for it?

Comment: @AvinashRaj it is minetest-classic

Comment: @terdon I open the unity home, and type _minetest_

Comment: How did you "search for it". the command locate uses a database that is updated every 24 hours. Try `sudo updatedb`, then `locate command` or `which command`.

Comment: Also, in gerneral, you should install packages from the Ubutnu repositories or a ppa. If the package is not in the repositories, install from source. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo . You should try to avoid alien or use it as a last resort as alien often causes problems due to differneces between distros (lib and binary names / locations) and post-install scripts (aline handles these poorly if at all).

Comment: The thing is, I tried compiling, and I always end up with something erroneous.`alien` just made my life easier, but I just can't find it!

Comment: It does not look as if alien made anything easier. If you got an error, alien is not going to resolve the problem. You need to provide additional information as requested above + the error message you received. I assume the .tar.gz contains source code, and thus needs to be compiled, and alien is not going to compile. tar.gz is just an archive, like a zip file. Some distros (Slackware) distribute compiled binaries in .tar.gz, and it is those compiled binaries alien would convert. You are going about this all wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to get a look into the converted deb file using your preferred Archive Manager. Does it contain the files you want? (Have a look into the `data.tar.gz` inside the deb file)

If it does, they should be on your disk where they are located in the archive. Check these locations on your disk. If the files are there, what's your problem?

If you're just missing the launcher file (The one listed in Dash/Application Menu), create one yourself.

EDIT: You tried to install the sources. That won't work of course. The minetest repo contains precompiled packages, why don't you use them. Or just get it via APT, like stated in Downloads/Debian.